# BASH - Manipulating a URL

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm busy with a script in bash that's job is to move content from a sub directory to the main directory of an FTP root. If the files should contain a database then the script must update all the SQL entries in the database.

The MySQL queries are not the issue but getting the values for search and replace is evading me.

## For example:

I have a site in http:// example.com/mysub

I need to move it to http:// example.com and change the database

I need to remove the http:// from http:// example.com/mysub so I can run a search and replace the values with example.com

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is confusingly worded, at least to me. You want to replace every instance of `example.com/sub` with `example.com/` in a set of text files?

Comment: If yes, then you can do it with sed, no need to first remove the `http://`

Comment: Apologies is does seem quite confusing now that I'm reading it again.

The solution posted by karakfa may do the trick actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's_\bhttps?://__'
```

also handles https,
example

```
$ echo "http://example.com" | sed -r 's_\bhttps?://__'
example.com

$ echo "https://example.com" | sed -r 's_\bhttps?://__'
example.com
```

Comment: I was trying to use sed but missed the the ? before the :

This should work thank you! Going to try and use it now

Comment: Is it possible to run sed on a variable?

Comment: `echo` or `printf` $var and pipe to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable *extglob* (`shot -s extglob`) and run the following *Parameter Expansion**:

```
var='https://example.com'
printf '%s\n' "${var#http?(s)://}"
```

Which will remove the first occurrence of `http://` or `https://` from the left side of `var`.

---

*Parameter Expansion** : Execute `man bash | less +/Parameter\ Expansion` or read further at [Bash FAQ 37](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073). Or both!